# How do you use an API with multiple pages?

Tags: json, swift, api

I want to load all the data from an API with 131 pages into the cells of a tableview. It can work for the first 60 pages of the API, but after that it stops working.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

var players = [Datum]()
var metadata = Meta(totalPages: 0, currentPage: 0, nextPage: 0, perPage: 0, totalCount: 0)
var playerOneSearches = [Datum]()
var url = URL(string: "https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players")
//var pageNumber = 2

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    getData(url: url!)
}

func changePage() {
    print(metadata.currentPage)
    if (metadata.nextPage != TID_NULL) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?page=\(metadata.nextPage)")
        getData(url: url!)
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var playerOneSearchBar: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var playerOneTableView: UITableView!

func getData(url:URL) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data,reponse,error in
            if error==nil {
                do {
                    let downloadedPlayers = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data!)
                    self.players += downloadedPlayers.data
                    self.metadata = downloadedPlayers.meta
                    self.playerOneSearches = self.players
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.playerOneTableView.reloadData()
                        self.changePage()
                    }
                    } catch{
                        print("Json Error")
                    }
                }
    }.resume()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return playerOneSearches.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = playerOneTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "playerOneCell")!
    cell.textLabel?.text = playerOneSearches[indexPath.row].lastName.capitalized
    return cell
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    playerOneSearches = []
    
    if searchText == "" {
        playerOneSearches = players
    }
    else {
        for player in players {
            if player.lastName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
                playerOneSearches.append(player)
            }
        }
    }
    self.playerOneTableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

When I run this code, it only displays the data in the tableview up until page 60. It says there is a JSON Error for page 61. Why doesn't it work after page 61 and how can I fix this?

Comment: `print("Json Error")` => `print("Json Error: \(error)")`. Redo it, and give us the new output.

Comment: This is the output:  Json Error : dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})))

Comment: Print the data (in String) when it's happening.

Answer (score 0):

with a long list of data there is something called paging. Where you get large chunks of data that will make up all the data. So you will need to get the paged data in chunks to make up the whole data set you are trying to grab. With the api you are using they are paging a size of 60.

[This might help you](https://weekly.elfitz.com/2019/12/19/swiftly-deal-with-pagination-in-swift/)

In addition search up pagination related to your topic or look inside of the web api you are using to get the data